# How can I bind functions with component in angular8 router events?

Tags: angular

In angular8, I generate a service that use Router to subscribe router change, and get the component instance, so I call the function use this component. But the `this` in function is not the component. how can I bind the component when I call the function in the service?

The service

```
this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => this.activatedRoute),
        map((route) => {
          while (route.firstChild) {
            route = route.firstChild;
          }
          return route;
        }),
        filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
      )
      .subscribe((event: any) => {
        event.component.prototype.test && event.component.prototype.test();
     });
 }
```

the component

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'xx',
})
export class TestComponent{
  title = "test string";

  test(){
   console.log(this.title); // the result is undefined
  }
}
```

I tried `event.component.prototype.test().bind(event.component)` but not work, can anyone help me out? thanks.

Comment: Typically you would call a method of a service. Why do you need to call the method on the component?

Comment: Actually  I need to call the methods of the components in my lib.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments it is not good practice to use the component method inside the service. Instead, you can inform the component according to the change as per the service class.

let say we have service name as TestService, just declare a `Subject` which we use to communicate. Just call the `next` method of `Subject` to propagate information to component.

```
export class TestService {
  readonly inform$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(() => this.activatedRoute),
    map((route) => {
      while (route.firstChild) {
        route = route.firstChild;
      }
      return route;
    }),
    filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
  );

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
}
```

Inject your service in component and execute your method as you receive specific notification from service.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'xx',
})
export class TestComponent {
  title = "test string";

  constructor(private readonly testService: TestService) {
    this.testService.inform$.subscribe((value) => { 
      // call your method here.
      this.test();
    })
  }

  test(){
    console.log(this.title); // the result is undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, ideally you want the subscription to the subject in the `ngOnInit()` rather than the constructor.

Comment: Right, thanks for the edit. I just wanted to convey the information here.

Comment: Thansk for your answer, Your method can be used but I want to define a callback function, like life cycle.
I still face how to bind the function to component in project when I call  it in my private lib.

Comment: Can you please explain why do you want it that way even when it is not recommended. Let say we have more than  one instance of same component, then it can make more issues.

Comment: I only need to add a callback function on the component, so I don't need to set up a listener on the component, which I think is more convenient.
I wrote a service earlier when I was doing route reuse. When deleting the data of the current route, I also need to call the 'ngOnDestroy' method of the component, but the 'ngOnDestroy' method of the component cannot get the reference of the current component.